# R: recodificar variable caracter

Tags: r

Tengo una variable de texto con observaciones. Quiero crear una nueva que valga 0 si no aparecen observaciones y 1 si sí aparecen.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo identificar que "no hay observación"? el dato es `NA` o es una cadena en blanco?

Comment: Es una cadena en blanco

Comment: Entonces podrias hacer algo así `df$tiene_observacion <- df$Observacion != ""`

Comment: Ha funcionado, gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes algo asi:

```
df = data.frame(var = c("1", "2", "3", NA, "", "4", NA, "", ""))
```

Usando la función mutate, puedes crear otras variables en tu df

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(nueva_var = ifelse(is.na(var), 0, 1))
```

Usando el ifelse, creas la condicion de que cuando encuentre un valor faltante, lo reemplaze por un cero y si no por un 1.

Ahora por otro lado, si lo que tienes son cadenas en blanco, aplicar el mismo truco

```
df %>% mutate(nueva_var = ifelse(var == "", 0, 1))
```